# Automatically start sshd in rescue/single user mode

Tags: ssh

I have been modifying partitions, and forgot to update fstab. On reboot, a mount fails and the system ends up in rescue/single user mode. This then means a trip to the server room (or get kvm access if remote), to type:

```
mkdir /var/run/sshd
/usr/sbin/sshd -f /etc/ssh/sshd_config_single_user # This config permits root login
```

After having done this twice, I wonder if I it is possible to have this run automatically when entering rescue mode? This is on Ubuntu 18.04.3.

Comment: Think about this.  You have the root / mount point, you COULD populate it with /etc and /var to support SSH daemon in rescue mode.  And those directory will disappear when /var mount point comes back.  Is it a potential security hole? Yes.

Comment: In my case, /var and /etc are already mounted in rescue mode.